# How can I test a function with void return value when using cunit

Tags: c, testing, cunit

I have a function that I need to test with cunit.
The function looks like this:

```
void server(unsigned short port) {
    int sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock_fd < 0) {
        perror("server: socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    memset(&server.sin_zero, 0, 8);

    if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("server: bind");
        close(sock_fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(sock_fd, MAX_BACKLOG) < 0) {
        perror("server: listen");
        close(sock_fd);
        exit(1);
    }
    ......
}
```

How can I test this function using cunit?

Comment: You need to ask yourself, *what* you want to test. Then you can write a test for it. This approach is independent of the specific unit-testing framework. -- For example, you can replace the real functions like `socket()`, `bind()` and so on with your own mocks to check if they are called correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As busy bee said, this function, does something which is even more important than the value it might have returned. I don't have a lot of experience but here is what I'd do :

- Create `__stub_` functions to wrap the `__real_` functions. These might be `socket()`, `perror()`, `exit()`, `memset()`, `bind()`, `close()`, `listen()`. you probably don't need them all so ask your self which matters. you can litterally wrap any function (with gcc at least) which means substitute all calls to `foo()` by calls to `__stub_foo()`. The architecture I used to see for the `foo_stub.c` file is :

```c
#include <xtypes>
#include "foo.h"
bool_t m_stubbed = FALSE;
void __stub_foo(void);
something foo_peek_value(void);
extern void __real_foo(void);
void __stub_foo(void){
if(m_stubbed){
   /* test code */
 }else{
   __real_foo();
 }
}
something foo_peek_value(void){
 return /* an interesting variable */
}
```

additionally call gcc with `-Wl --wrap=foo`.

- Create a test file which setups the foo stub (by switching `m_stubbed` to true), make the test routine call foo(), and then check the outcome with a `CU_ASSERT_EQUAL(foo_peek_value(), 42);` (42 standing for the solution). Eventually add a teardown function to deactivate the stub.

Best of luck